# cxf does not generate the expected type in WSDL

Tags: xsd, jaxb, wsdl, cxf

I have an exception:

```
    public class MyException extends Exception {    
        public MyException() {
        }
        public MyException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }
```

The exception is thrown from a webservice method.

When I generate the Webservice using a regular Jax-ws implementation, the WSDL has:

```
    <xs:complexType name='MyException'>
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='message' type='xs:string' />
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

But, when generating the webservice with **cxf**, I get:

```
<xs:complexType name='MyException'> <xs:sequence/></xs:complexType>
```

Which is not ok for me: I expect to get the first variant.

Can you please advise how to force CXF to provide the desired result?
Remark: I cannot alter the code in the exception! The Exception does not have any fields!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already reported and fixed in the latest CXF versions:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4748

Comment: Sorry, in the jira issue, the Exception had a field, I do not have one, so my problem is different.

Comment: Same basic issue though: the message is not mapped.